# How can I change the putting camera angle?

Tags: tiger-woods-pga-tour-14

I have been playing around with the visual presentation settings to my personal preference... but I can't seem to change the camera view that is shown when I put the ball ( the action of the ball rolling to the hole ).  The camera seems to be random but from my experiences, the camera angle is shown from where the fans are standing (next to the green) - which IMHO ruins the *intense/thrilling* part of the putt.

How can I change this angle to be shown of more from an eagle's eye or above the ball view ?

*I will try to post a picture of what I am talking about soon*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the left analog stick when not in approach shot view.